# Reading newline from previous input when reading from keyboard with fgets()

Tags: c++

I have a problem reading input from user using fgets(), when I try to read the input and hit enter it affects the next input, it automatically reads the new line character and messes everything up. Some people here told me to use strcspn() function to get rid of that new line character. However it still doesn't work for me. To be more specific the age field is the one with the problem, I set the age character array to be 4, because the max age is 3 digit number and we need an extra space for the null character. When I use fgets() with the age field I also read 4 characters, at most 3 places for the age, and the last place for string termination, but it doesn't work and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
struct Person {

    char name[20];
    char age[4];

};

int main(){

    vector<Person> v;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        Person p;
        printf("Enter a name and age:\n");
        printf("Name: ");
        fgets(p.name, 20, stdin);
        p.name[strcspn(p.name,"\n")] = '\0';
        printf("Age: ");
        fgets(p.age, 4, stdin);
        p.age[strcspn(p.age, "\n")] = '\0';


        v.push_back(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't c, it's c++ (vector...) using c constructs.

Comment: @xing Do I need to update both the fgets() and age array capacity, or just the fgets()?

Comment: How about `int age; cin >> age;`?

Comment: @JazzSoft I know about cin, but I wanted to do it in C, I just used the vector as a convenient storage place.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets( char *str, int count, FILE *stream )` reads at most `count - 1` characters from the given file stream. Then `fgets(...,4,...)` takes at most 3 characters from the stream, which is one less than necessary to read in 3 digits + a new line. So the new line remains in the stream and is consumed by the next `fgets`, leading to an empty `p.name`. This could be corrected by using `age[5]` and `fgets(...,5,...)`.

The main issue is, however, that your code is vulnerable to "incorrect" (i.e. to long) user input, such that an input like `"123   \n"` would again lead to unexpected results. To make it a bit more stable, you could accept more characters in a line but then truncate the input if necessary:

```
void readin(char* dest, size_t destSize) {
  char input[1000];
  fgets(input, 1000, stdin);
  input[strcspn(input,"\n")] = '\0';
  strncpy(dest,input, destSize);
  dest[destSize-1] = '\0';
}

void main() {
  ...
  readin(p.name,20);
  readin(p.age,4);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but if I declare a buffer with size of 1000, when I at most need 20 for example, isn't it considered memory wasting?

Comment: The buffer is just temporary memory for taking over the input, not for storing the (truncated) values, so it is actually not a waste. 1000 bytes of temporary memory is usually not considered as any problem in most systems today. But you are of course free to shrink the size...